# How can i close a FrameView java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, modal-dialog, jdialog

I've tried everything and i cant get with the answer, there is not much topics talking about it.

Here the escenario:

Once the user run the app, 2 FrameViews display. The main frame and the login.
Whenever if the user exist, the login frameview must be close and let me edit the main_frame.

But i cannot close the login frameview. Dispose doesnt exist, close neither. What do i have to do?

the login form is name

```
demo
```

and the main_frame

```
main_frame
```

Suggestions?

Update

HERE the code where the login login must be close

```
 private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 

        String pass = this.jTextField1.getText();
        String user = this.jTextField2.getText();

        boolean login = db.Qboolean(new String[]{
            "SELECT Id_User FROM login WHERE UserName = ?  AND Pass = ?",
            pass +","+user,

        });

        if(login)
       //what do i have to use here to close it!!!


        else
            Logs.Mensaje("No se pudo :(");

    }
```

Comment: How about showing us your code? FrameView is not a standard swing (and even Java) class, so I'm not even sure, from your question, if you're really using swing.

Comment: Done, if thats not what you are looking for, you can tell me what part of code you want

Comment: The part I'd like to see is the part where you're trying to close the login frame or dialog, siwnce that's where the problem is.

Comment: Check now. Hope that code is what you need.

Comment: Take a look at [JFrame#dispose](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()) and [JFrame#setVisible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible(boolean))

Comment: The log-in should be a modal dialog or an option pane.  This is discussed about every 8 hours on SO.  See [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) & [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Netbeans , there is another way (and easy) to check username and password !
you can define a new Jfram in run(){  }

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

public void run() {
//here you can make log in form within while and check if the user is exist 
//continue 

 new Graphic().setVisible(true);


}
```